# "GET /css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2578

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I'm new to Django and this is my first time using it. I keep getting the error "GET /css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2578" I've already looked through other solutions posted and none have helped. I've followed the documentation exactly as laid out by [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/), but it still isn't working.

Relevant settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')),)
]
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en"><head>
    ...
    <link href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>...
```

Relevant urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('App1.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

[image: Here is an image of my current directory]

EDIT: It was a simple fix. I simply forgot to add an "S" at the end of `STATICFILES_DIR`. It is supposed to be `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: Check you `DEBUG` value in **settings.py** file it should set to ***True*** and it's **`STATICFILES_DIRS`** not **`STATICFILES_DIR`**

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Debug was already true. Also, thanks for catching the staticfiles_dirs. I didn't even see that. It works now, thank you. I can't believe I missed that lol.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is probably that your index.html file is in a templates folder and not your main Project1 folder. The code is searching for a file with the path templates/static/css/styles.css, which doesn't exist (404 error). Try moving your index.html file outside of your templates folder and see if it works.

Comment: After doing that, the webpage doesn't render and I get this error: 'django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html'
My DIRS template is currently set for "templates" would it make sense then to change it into the main Project1 folder?